# Part moving towards screen?

Tags: roblox

The part is supposed to move to the mouse's position and it worked almost fine but the thing is it moves towards my screen...

Local script:

```
local moveevent = script:WaitForChild("MoveEvent")

script.Parent.Parent.Equipped:Connect(function(mouse)
mouse.Move:Connect(function()
    moveevent:FireServer(mouse.Hit.p)
end)
end)
```

Script:

```
local moveevent = script.Parent:WaitForChild("MoveEvent")


moveevent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, mousepos)
    workspace:WaitForChild("Spawnpart").Position = mousepos
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In local script:

```lua
mouse.TargetFilter = workspace:WaitForChild("Spawnpart")
```

What's happening is that your mouse it hitting the part instead of what's behind it. [Read more](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Mouse/TargetFilter)